# Domino designer display field after click

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

In form I have button, i want display field "Price" after button "Save" click, it's possible ?
Or can be solution to add to field HTML atribute "readonly".

Comment: Maybe, as You mentioned Yourself - add another HTML field - price, which by default would be hidden, and then un-hidden/updated, once "save" is pressed. No need to complicate things.

Comment: If you want to show the Price in form as a read only field then have a look at field types "computed" or "computed for display": http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_ABOUT_EDITABLE_AND_COMPUTED_FIELDS.html

Comment: If you want to show an OK dialogbox with Price after clicking "Save" button then use @Prompt([OK]; ...) http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_PROMPT.html

Comment: Is this application going to run in the Notes client or in a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, enable option "Generate HTML for all fields" (check the image below):

[image]

It will generate html for all fields, even for hidden ones.

Add field `price` to the form and hide id by paragraph hide formulas according to your requirements.

When you have saved your form, add a flag to your document, that turns the hide formula for `price` field to false, and invoke the command:

```
@Command( [RefreshHideFormulas] );
```

It will make your `price` field visible.